# Google Maps Open In Selected City

Tags: javascript, html

I have [This Map](http://jsfiddle.net/gZK2g/3/) I am working on and it opens at San Francisco. I would like to change this to open at a specified town, country of my choice. (i.e. London, England or Javea, Spain) The location changes on every page of my site and the "Town & Country" are inserted in the page from a database.

```plain
Example: {$listing_city} = Town {$listing_country} = Country
```

The search box at the top is not needed as I want to show the local restaurants, bars, doctors in that area. However, the search box can stay I just want the map to open in the respective town.

I am new hear and wondered if anyone can help.

Thanks in advance

Mal

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Google Developers</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_static/css/screen.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//www.google.com/cse/style/look/default.css" type="text/css" />
    <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script id="jqueryui" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.10/jquery-ui.min.js" defer async></script>
    <script src="//www.google.com/jsapi?key=AIzaSyCrlr1LScCevQ1epeHArLVww0eHlB6o1wg"></script>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body class="docs framebox_body">
          <script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript">
          var map, places, iw;
          var markers = [];
          var autocomplete;

          function initialize() {
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.783259, -122.402708);
            var myOptions = {
              zoom: 12,
              center: myLatlng,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);
            places = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', tilesLoaded);
            autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('autocomplete'));
            google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
              showSelectedPlace();
            });
          }

          function tilesLoaded() {
            google.maps.event.clearListeners(map, 'tilesloaded');
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', search);
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', search);
            search();
          }

          function showSelectedPlace() {
            clearResults();
            clearMarkers();
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            map.panTo(place.geometry.location);
            markers[0] = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: place.geometry.location,
              map: map
            });
            iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              content: getIWContent(place)
            });
            iw.open(map, markers[0]);
          }

          function search() {
            var type;
            for (var i = 0; i < document.controls.type.length; i++) {
              if (document.controls.type[i].checked) {
                type = document.controls.type[i].value;
              }
            }

            autocomplete.setBounds(map.getBounds());

            var search = {
              bounds: map.getBounds()
            };

            if (type != 'establishment') {
              search.types = [type];
            }

            places.search(search, function(results, status) {
              if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                clearResults();
                clearMarkers();
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                  markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: results[i].geometry.location,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
                  });
                  google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', getDetails(results[i], i));
                  setTimeout(dropMarker(i), i * 100);
                  addResult(results[i], i);
                }
              }
            });
          }

          function clearMarkers() {
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
              if (markers[i]) {
                markers[i].setMap(null);
                markers[i] == null;
              }
            }
          }

          function dropMarker(i) {
            return function() {
              markers[i].setMap(map);
            }
          }

          function addResult(result, i) {
            var results = document.getElementById('results');
            var tr = document.createElement('tr');
            tr.style.backgroundColor = (i% 2 == 0 ? '#F0F0F0' : '#FFFFFF');
            tr.onclick = function() {
              google.maps.event.trigger(markers[i], 'click');
            };

            var iconTd = document.createElement('td');
            var nameTd = document.createElement('td');
            var icon = document.createElement('img');
            icon.src = result.icon.replace('http:', '');
            icon.setAttribute('class', 'placeIcon');
            var name = document.createTextNode(result.name);
            iconTd.appendChild(icon);
            nameTd.appendChild(name);
            tr.appendChild(iconTd);
            tr.appendChild(nameTd);
            results.appendChild(tr);
          }

          function clearResults() {
            var results = document.getElementById('results');
            while (results.childNodes[0]) {
              results.removeChild(results.childNodes[0]);
            }
          }

          function getDetails(result, i) {
            return function() {
              places.getDetails({
                reference: result.reference
              }, showInfoWindow(i));
            }
          }

          function showInfoWindow(i) {
            return function(place, status) {
              if (iw) {
                iw.close();
                iw = null;
              }

              if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                  content: getIWContent(place)
                });
                iw.open(map, markers[i]);
              }
            }
          }

          function getIWContent(place) {
            var content = '<table style="border:0"><tr><td style="border:0;">';
            content += '<img class="placeIcon" src="' + place.icon + '"></td>';
            content += '<td style="border:0;"><b><a href="' + place.url + '">' + place.name + '</a></b>';
            content += '</td></tr></table>';
            return content;
          }

          google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
          </script>

          <style type="text/css">
            html, body {
              margin: 0;
              padding: 0;
              height: 100%;
              font-family: arial;
              font-size: 13px;
              overflow: hidden;
            }

            #map_canvas {
              float: left;
              width: 420px;
              height: 406px;
            }

            #listing {
              float: left;
              margin-left: 1px;
              width: 210px;
              height: 406px;
              overflow: auto;
              cursor: pointer;
            }
            #controls {
              padding: 5px;
            }
            .placeIcon {
              width: 16px;
              height: 16px;
              margin: 2px;
            }
            #results {
              border-collapse: collapse;
              width: 184px;
            }
            #locationField {
              margin-left: 1px;
            }
            #autocomplete {
              width: 516px;
              border: 1px solid #ccc;
            }
          </style>
          <div id="locationField">
            <input id="autocomplete" type="text">
          </div>
          <div id="map_canvas"></div>
          <div id="listing">
            <div id="controls">
              <form name="controls">
                <!--<input type="radio" name="type" value="establishment" onclick="search()" checked="checked"/>All<br/>-->
                <input type="radio" name="type" value="restaurant" onclick="search()" />Restaurants<br/>
                  <input type="radio" name="type" value="police" onclick="search()" />Police Station<br/>
                  <input type="radio" name="type" value="church" onclick="search()" />Churches<br/>
                  <input type="radio" name="type" value="doctor" onclick="search()" />Doctor<br/>
                  <input type="radio" name="type" value="bar" onclick="search()" />Bars<br/>
                  <input type="radio" name="type" value="bank" onclick="search()" />Banks<br/>
              </form>
            </div>
            <table id="results"></table>
          </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to know latitude of towns you want. Than on every page you need to change this lines in **initialize()** function from

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.783259, -122.402708);
```

to

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(changeTHIS, andTHIS);
```

here is example for London

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.507222, -0.1275);
```

Comment: Thanks Paka appreciate your help.

Is there a way to do this automaticly from the page variable? Each page already has a unique variable, fed from a database i.e."Town" , "City" , "Zip Code" and Country.

Comment: @Mal  can you add latitude and longitude to you database? if yes, then you need to modify your page template in such way that this variables appears in page as javascript variables:
`<script>
var lat = 'INFO FROM DATABASE',
    lng = INFO FROM DATABASE';
</script>`

and then modify initialize function:

`var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);`